# How do I collect Java exceptions from Kubernetes pods?

Tags: exception, logging, kubernetes, monitoring, kubernetes-pod

I am looking for a way to collect Java exceptions thrown by containers. I know the function from the logging system of GKE/GCP and would like to implement a similar logging system in our self-hosted cluster.

I am using Prometheus and Grafana for monitoring metrics.

Comment: What you are asking for, is already built in GCP. You can simply filter the errors in the logging system. Am I not understanding the question or missing something? If you need help I can explain in an answer step-by-step or provide some references

Comment: can you define what exceptions you are trying to catch? if it's app logs, then fluentd/bit will be able to ingest/parse logs

Comment: Sorry, my question was not precise enough.  I'm looking for a way to log exceptions like in GKE in our self-hosted cluster. I mentioned GKE as an example because I know the function there and want to implement similar logging in our cluster. I will edit the Question. @NeoAnderson

Comment: @Matt I want to catch thrown Java exceptions. I will have a look at fluentd/bit. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a centralized logging solution. There are some common solutions out there. One of them is the ELK Stack (now named Elastic stack).

It has 3 main components:

1. **Elasticsearch:** To store the logs, index them, make them searchable etc.
2. **Logstash:** To collect the logs from various sources (containers in your case), parse/filter them and push them to other systems. In ELK's case, push them to Elasticsearch.
3. **Kibana:** A web GUI to visualize the data in Elasticsearch, allows searching, creating visual graphs and so on.

See the official page of [Elastic stack](https://www.elastic.co/what-is/elk-stack) for more information.

You can also use [Fluentd](https://www.fluentd.org/) or [Fluent Bit](https://fluentbit.io/) instead of Logstash, so it'll be an EFK stack. I personally had pretty good experience with an EFK stack with Fluent Bit.

For another, lighter alternative, you can check out [Grafana Loki](https://grafana.com/oss/loki/), which is kind of a logging extension to the popular monitoring setup of Prometheus+Grafana.

Comment: Thank you. I am now using Grafana Loki together with Promtail and it works really well and is easy to use.

Comment: @bennex I’m glad to be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are already familiar with the Stackdriver solution from GKE, I'd bet your best choice would be to stick with it and install Stackdriver on your self managed Kubernetes cluster as well:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/logging-stackdriver/